# How to get the data in snowflake for past 24 months in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I have the data for the current month in Snowflake which I am extracting with the below mentioned query

```
select distinct HPOLICY
              , ANNUALPREMIUMAMOUNT
              , year(dateadd(year, 0, CURRENT_DATE))
              , month(dateadd(month, 0, CURRENT_DATE)) yearmonth
from hub_test
```

I want to extrapolate this data to the past 24 months which means get the same data with Sep 2019, Aug 2019 and so on till past 24 months.

Answer (score 0):

That query is get *all time* distinct data, and put a fake current year/month column on it.

If you where doing something like:

```
select distinct HPOLICY
    ,ANNUALPREMIUMAMOUNT
    ,date_part('year', date_column) as year
    ,date_part('month', date_column) as month 
from hub_test
where date_column >= date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE());
```

you would have the current months data, if `date_column` was the date_of the data in the row.

Therefore to get the last 24 months you would alter that to:

```
select distinct HPOLICY
    ,ANNUALPREMIUMAMOUNT
    ,date_part('year', date_column) as year
    ,date_part('month', date_column) as month 
from hub_test
where date_column >= dateadd('month',-24, date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE()));
```